# Working out a plane defined by $|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Well Complex Analysis is not my good friend but I am working on it, since it is part of what i should learn. I was asked to Describe geometrically the sets of point$z$ in the complex plane defined by the following relations. Hints welcomed

$$|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$$

where $$ z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C$$

Comment: Hint: $|z-w|$ is the distance from $z$ to $w.$

Comment: Think about what the absolute value means in the complex plane. $|z - z_0|$ is the distance between $z$ and $z_0$. So here we have two distances equal to each other i.e. the distance from $z_1$ and $z_2$ is the same. You take it from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for all points $z$ whose distance to $z_1$ and $z_2$ are equal. Draw the perpendicular bisector to the segment from  $z_1$ to $z_2$ and think about what the picture is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can find the point $c$ on the plane that is colinear with $z_1$ and $z_2$ (use pythag), then for any point on the plane $x$, the angles $\angle x c z_1 = \angle x c z_2 = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

That is the plane becomes $\{x ~:~ (x - c) ~\circ~ (z_1 - c) = (x - c) ~\circ~ (z_2 - c) = 0\}$ where I am using $\circ$ for dot product.

Comment: I am confused what do down vote mean? is this not correct?

Comment: @user249954 I ignore downvoters who can't be bothered to leave a reason.  Some people are just trolls.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Sorry but how does this "describe geometrically the sets of pointz in the complex plane defined by the following relations..."?

Comment: @Did "All points that form a right angles with $c~z_1$ and $c~z_2$.  It might not be the geometric description you have in mind, but it is a geometric description.

Comment: It is geometric -- and not related to the problem (at least, not obviously, not to me).

Comment: @Did thank you, I'll work on making clearer explanations, I guess I've just gotten a bit lazy.